# jQuery - Remove object from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an object from an array with

delete array[index]

which is deleting the object from the array however the .length property of the array is still == 1

Any ideas?

PS I'm trying to delete a question e.g. topic->questions[question_id]

[image]

```
if(topic_array[topic_id] !== 'undefined'){
            if(topic_array[topic_id].questions.length > 0){
                for(var i = 0; i < topic_array[topic_id].questions.length; i++){
                    if(topic_array[topic_id].questions[i].question_id == question_id){
                        delete topic_array[topic_id].questions[i];
                        console.log(topic_array);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `delete`, you want [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
topic_array[topic_id].questions.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: topic_array[topic_id].questions.splice(i, 1) (splice on the questions array). Many thanks Elliot